# Weird space between td and its border element : CSS tables

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I am trying to create a CSS table with border all over using the standard method of applying top and left borders to all `td` elements (apart from those in first column and first row). And then there is a border on the `<table>`. This method suits my use-case better than one in which we use `border-collapse`.

But then there is a bug which resembles inner margin on td elements. This margin like space isn't always there but only occurs on some viewports for some reason. Here's my code:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;  
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

table {
    font-size: 15px;

    border-spacing: 0;
    
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 35px 35px 0 0;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: none;

    width: 90vw;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    box-sizing: content-box;

    border-left: 4px solid black;
    border-top: 4px solid black;
    height: 60px;
}

thead td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 35px;
}

thead td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 33px;
}

thead td {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

table button {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    background-color: white;
    color: #d90429;
}

.progress-bar{
    background-color: orange;
}

.progress-bar > div{
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Task Type</td>
                <td>Target Time (in Minutes)</td>
                <td>Percentage Achieved</td>
                <td>Add/Delete Tasks</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Maths</td>
                <td>120</td>
                <td class="progress-bar">
                    <div>50</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's one viewport in which this bug can be seen in action:
[image]

I guess running above code snippet and looking at the output in full screen will reproduce this bug

**EDIT**

1. As pointed out by KIKOSoftware in comments, the problem seems to be specific to chrome.
2. My Version of Chrome happens to use 3.991px for border instead of 4px.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with either Chrome, Edge or Firefox on Windows 11. I assume you mean the very narrow yellow line surrounding the green area? Your _"but only occurs on some viewports for some reason"_ is a bit vague. What viewports?

Comment: I know this can feel ugly, but I think that the best solution is to create another table inside the `<td>`. In this way, every column will look alike

Comment: In other words: `<td><table><tr>green<td></td><td>yellow</td></tr></table></td>`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware by viewports I meant this error can be seen only for some screen sizes. Try resizing browser window to see if it happens

Comment: @CristianTraìna Tried the nested table solution, but that doesn't seem to work, the same narrow line still appears

Comment: I did resize the browser window, and tried full screen, which didn't make any difference. I didn't expect it either. What browser, and what OS are you using? I mentioned it intentionally, to see if it differed from what you're using.

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware for bearing with me. I'm using Windows 11 and Chrome 102.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on a personal level, having had a thousand problems with borders in HTML tables,
I ended up opting for a radical solution: no border at all!
I use `border-collapse: separate;` and I play on `border-spacing`
*in addition it lightens the css to write*

I recommend it

in your case:

```css
* {
  padding : 0;  
  margin  : 0;
  }
html, body {
  height : 100%;
  width  : 100%;
  background-color: #658d8d;  /* this one is mine... */
  }
.table-container {
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  align-items    : center;
  padding-bottom : 50px;
  font-size      : 20px;
  margin: 1em;
  }
table {
  font-size        : 15px;
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 4px;
  background-color : black;
  border-radius    : 33px 33px 0  0;
  width            : 90vw;
  }
thead td {
  font-size    : 20px;
  font-weight  : 500;
  }
td {
  background-color : white;
  height           : 60px;
  text-align       : center;
}
thead td:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 29px;  }
thead td:last-child  { border-top-right-radius: 29px; }

table button {
  cursor           : pointer;
  height           : 100%;
  width            : 100%;
  border           : 0;
  background-color : white;
  color            : #d90429;
  }
.progress-bar {
  background-color: orange;
  }
.progress-bar > div {
  background-color : green;
  height           : 100%;
  width            : 50%
  }
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Task Type</td>
        <td>Target Time (in Minutes)</td>
        <td>Percentage Achieved</td>
        <td>Add/Delete Tasks</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Maths</td>
        <td>120</td>
        <td class="progress-bar"><div>50</div></td>
        <td><button type="button">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```